# Why use virtual functions when deriving hides base function?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

So heres my code:

```
#include <iostream>

class cBase
{
    public:
    void vf(int)
    {
        std::cout << "cBase\n";
    }
};

class cDerived : public cBase
{
    public:
    void vf(int)
    {
        std::cout << "cDerived\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    cBase b;
    cDerived d;

    b.vf(0);
    d.vf(0);
}
```

This example hides the function `vf()` of the base class and calls the `vf()` function of the derived class. Heres another piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>

class cBase
{
    public:
    virtual void vf(int)
    {
        std::cout << "cBase\n";
    }
};

class cDerived : public cBase
{
    public:
    void vf(int)
    {
        std::cout << "cDerived\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    cBase b;
    cDerived d;

    b.vf(0);
    d.vf(0);
}
```

Now, the `vf()` function of the derived class overrides the `vf()` function of the vase class.

So my question is: what is the point of virtual functions if i can achieve the same result with the default hiding mechanism of c++? Am i missing something here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `cBase *b = new cDerived; b->vf(0);` <= try this with both your samples.

Comment: The virtual method guarantees that, if a derived class has the same function, the program will use the derived function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make polymorphism work you need to work on pointers or references. When you use dot operator on object that is neither pointer or reference then virtual table is not used to call proper virtual function.

To see how it works, create derived object dynamically, assign it to base class pointer and call your function on it. This will call implementation from your derived class.

Comment: This isn't true, the dot operator call's the most derived version of a virtual function, even when used via a reference to a base class.

Comment: Right, forgot about reference

Answer (score 1):

`virtual` functions give *run time* polymorphism. Your objects will not exhibit run time polymorphism which is when the same code using the same compile-time types can exhibit different behaviour based on the run time types of the objects in question. E.g:

```
void f(CBase& x) {
    x.vf(0);
}
```

Without `vf` being `virtual` in `CBase`, the `CBase::vf` will be called even if the run time type of `x` is `CDerived`.